# Swagger codegen can't correctly generate a controller method with array of "oneof" response

Tags: nestjs, swagger-codegen

I'm trying to generate a controller method through NestJS' swagger decorators.
A method should return an array of mixed ClassA and ClassB types, and the only solution I could find that returns that kind of response is

```
@ApiResponse({
  isArray: true,
  schema: {
    items: {
      oneOf: [
        { $ref: getSchemaPath(ClassA) },
        { $ref: getSchemaPath(ClassB) },
      ]
    }
  }
})

public generatedMethod(body: ..., observe?: 'response', reportProgress?: boolean): Observable<HttpResponse<Array<ClassA | ClassB>>>;
```

but at the same time generates the following import:

```
import { ClassAClassB } from '../model/classAClassB';
```

without generating the class file.

What am I missing in the schema definition?
Thanks in advance

Any other configuration would return either a generated "mixed class type", but not in an array format

```
export type MixedClass = ClassA | ClassB

public generatedMethod(body: ..., observe?: 'response', reportProgress?: boolean): Observable<HttpResponse<MixedClass>>;
```

or a whole wrong output

```
public generatedMethod(body: ..., observe?: 'response', reportProgress?: boolean): Observable<HttpResponse<Array<>>>
public generatedMethod(body: ..., observe?: 'response', reportProgress?: boolean): Observable<HttpResponse<any>>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to use other schemas, you need to add them using `@ApiExtraModels` at the top of the class.

```js
@ApiExtraModels(ClassA, ClassB) // Add this decorator
@Controller()
export class MyController {
    @ApiResponse({
    status: 200, // => **is added**
    isArray: true,
      schema: {
        items: {
          oneOf: [
            { $ref: getSchemaPath(ClassA) },
            { $ref: getSchemaPath(ClassB) },
          ]
        }
      }
    })
    myMethod(@Body body) {        
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope, the problem is not the missing generation of ClassA and ClassB, but the import request for ClassAClassB (that's an invalid, non-existent class)

Comment: Yes, you were right, but if you add a status property to something like 200, then the type of response will be assigned to the generated client code. Accordingly, I updated my answer.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but I had to return from holidays :> Anyway nope, adding the status doesn't change anything